# conditionally parsing a string in a mysql select

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make DNS zone transfers work in a BIND DLZ environment with a mysql backing for the dynamically loaded zone. Whoever set this up originally (I'm guessing on the 3rd of September 2013) did a really lazy job. Since fields like serial and expire are only used in SOA records, the values for all of those were just stuck in one field with spaces. This works for ordinary DNS use, but not zone transfers.

```
mysql> SELECT `data` FROM `bind` WHERE `zone`='example.com' AND `type`='SOA';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| data                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| core-dns-01.example.com. sysadmin.example.com. 2013090337 86400 3600 86400 3600 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For the zone transfer queries, according to http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/mysql_driver.html , I'll need to have those as separate values.

I've gotten as far as:

```
SELECT `ttl`, `type`, `host`, `mx_priority`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(                 `data`, ' ', 1)           AS `data`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS `resp_person`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS `serial`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 4), ' ', -1) AS `refresh`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 5), ' ', -1) AS `retry`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 6), ' ', -1) AS `expire`
   ,SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 7), ' ', -1) AS `minimum`
FROM `bind` WHERE `zone`='%zone%'
              AND `type`='SOA';
```

(Note that `%zone%` is special to BIND DLZ to substitute a query value; it is not a wildcard match.)

But this fails horribly when I use the proper query `WHERE zone='%zone%' AND (type='SOA' OR type='NS')` since the NS records have only a single value in them, which should be returned as `data`.

I've reached the end of my SQL know-how here. I really don't know how (or even if) I can make a single query that returns a parsed SOA and a non-parsed set of NS records (which would have `NULL` for the missing values). Can it be done? How?

Comment: Do you mean `zone='%zone%'` to do wildcard matching? You need to use `zone LIKE '%zone%'` for that. The `=` operator only does literal string matches.

Comment: The '%zone%' is substituted with the actual zone of the query by BIND DLZ. I updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method1

Add following statement before the semicolon. the union adds the rows of the second select behind the firest

```
Union 
SELECT `ttl`, `type`, `host`, NULL AS `mx_priority`
, `data`          AS `data`
,NULL AS `resp_person`
,NULL AS `serial`
,NULL AS `refresh`
,NULL AS `retry`
,NULL AS `expire`
,NULL AS `minimum`
FROM `bind` WHERE `zone`='%zone%'
          AND `type`='NS'
```

This gives you all NS records  according to

```
ttl = 3600
type = NS
host = @
data = NS1
all other fields in the row are NULL.
```

> Method2

As you can see you can check ever Column if it is SOA or NS and handle than the needed outcome. If you have more than two criteria you can switch to CASE WHEN or nested IFs.

```
SELECT `ttl`, `type`, `host`
 , IF(type='SOA',`mx_priority`,NULL) AS `mx_priority`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX(                 `data`, ' ', 1),`data`) AS `data`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 2), ' ', 
   -1),NULL) AS `resp_person`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 3), ' ',
    -1),NULL) AS `serial`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 4), ' ',
    -1),NULL) AS `refresh`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 5), ' ',
    -1),NULL) AS `retry`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 6), ' ',
   -1),NULL) AS `expire`
 ,IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ' ', 7), ' ',
    -1),NULL) AS `minimum`
 FROM `bind` WHERE `zone``zone`='%zone%'
          AND (type='SOA' or `type`='NS' )
```

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors (eg "`type`,, `host`"), both of these methods look good. Thanks.

Comment: I was mistaken in saying `host` was needed for the SOA and NS records. I got it working with `SELECT ttl, type, mx_priority, IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( data, ' ', 1), data) AS data , IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ' ', 2), ' ', -1),NULL ) AS resp_person , [...] IF(type='SOA',SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ' ', 7), ' ', -1),NULL ) AS minimum FROM bind WHERE zone='%zone%' AND (type='SOA' or type='NS' )`. This db has an `mx_priority` so no need to fake that one.